# Getting attendance of an employee with a date series in a particular range in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a attendance table with employee_id, date and punch-in time.

```
Emp_Id     PunchTime
101      10/10/2016 07:15
101      10/10/2016 12:20
101      10/10/2016 12:50
101      10/10/2016 16:31
102      10/10/2016 07:15
```

Here I have the date only for the working days. I want to get the attendance list of a employee with series of given date period. I need the day also. Result should look like as follows

```
date        |  day     |employee_id |   Intime          |     outtime       |
2016-10-09  |  sunday  |   101      |                   |                   |
2016-10-10  |  monday  |   101      | 2016-10-10 7:15AM |2016-10-10 4:31 PM |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of dates and then do an outer join on them:

The following displays all days in October:

```
select d.date, a.emp_id, 
       min(punchtime) as intime, 
       max(punchtime) as outtime
from generate_series(date '2016-10-01', date '2016-11-01' - 1, interval '1' day) as d (date)
  left join attendance a on d.date = a.punchtime::date
group by d.date, a.emp_id;
order by d.date, a.emp_id;
```

As you want the first and last timestamp from each day this can be done using a simple `group by` query.

This will however not repeat the emp_id for the non_existing days.

Comment: How can i generate date series continuously without missing any date in between? If there is no date in any particular date it should come as blank other than the date. For example, if i have holiday at Sunday, then my attendance will not be there., in that case i need to show in out blank but the date and day should be there.

Comment: @MohammedNisar: the `generate_series()` function does exactly that. I will generate one row for each day between 2016-10-01 and 2016-11-01 You can make that dynamic to generate that for all days between the first and last day stored in attendance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will generate a list of the range of dates (starting and ending with whatever range is found in your punchtime table), with employees and intime, outtime for each. Check the SQL fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d93bd/1

```
WITH RECURSIVE minmax AS
(
    SELECT MIN(CAST(time AS DATE)) AS min, MAX(CAST(time as DATE)) AS max
    FROM emp_time
),
dates AS
(
    SELECT m.min as datepart
    FROM minmax m
    RIGHT JOIN emp_time e ON m.min = CAST(e.time as DATE)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.datepart + 1 FROM dates d, minmax mm 
    WHERE d.datepart + 1 <= mm.max
)
SELECT d.datepart as date, e.emp, MIN(e.time) as intime, MAX(e.time) as outtime FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN emp_time e ON d.datepart = CAST(e.time as DATE)
GROUP BY d.datepart, e.emp
ORDER BY d.datepart;
```

Comment: Thanks.............. it worked for me after some small modifications according to my db structure.. thanks alot....